# Master/Details in windows form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, master-detail, datarepeater

I have the master details "pattern" in a windows form.
For example, I have a bill (master) with a list of items (details) the user will add.
However, the user will add the items manually.
In order to achieve this, I used the data repeater but it caused a lot of problems when the scroll appears. 
I spent several hours trying to fix this issue (the selected value in the combobox in the repeater gets mixed as the user scrolls down).

Are there any other controls anyone ever used for the same purpose?
I don't thing the DataGridView will provide me with the same flexibility.
Also building a complete set of dynamic controls is a huge overload.

Suggestions?

Note: I m using .net framework 4.5

Comment: 1- "Are there any other controls anyone ever used for the same purpose? " 2- I m looking for a similar control. 3-4 WinForms are clients requirements. Thanks :)

Comment: really? what kind of client asks you to use an inefficient framework that has been replaced by a much more scalable, faster, and that requires 10% the amount of development work in order to get a running product?

Comment: he has windows XP and not planning to move towards a newer version. WPF is a mess on XP

Comment: Not really. We have customers with XP machines and our WPF 4.0 Line of Business Application works excellent. Faster than any winforms crap and looks really professional (without resorting to HACKS such as owner draw)

Comment: I will take your recommendation into consideration, meanwhile i prefer to find a solution for the main problem, thanks